# Retrieve caller-ID in Microsoft Teams in realtime

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm trying to integrate Teams with an external service by using a Teams Bot/App. The app should call an external API with the caller-ID of the incoming PSTN call.

My success went so far, that I could get a list of the last calls but they were far away from being realtime and the caller-ID was masked.

Is it possible at all to "listen" to call metadata in realtime?

Comment: What do you mean for caller-id/ call id? Which API you are trying to call using bot? Could you please explain your scenario in more detail? Also could you please share repro steps?

Comment: Are you still facing the issue? Could you please update?

Answer (score 0):

You can Retrieve the Call id by Subscribe for Microsoft Graph change notifications to be notified when your user's data changes, so you don't have to poll for changes. check [Use the Microsoft Graph API to get change notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0) also check this [sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-webhooks-sample#creating-the-subscription). when you subscribe to call

Comment: Hi, from my understanding the subscription is not realtime but delayed by a few minutes.